# Firebase FCM error: Unregistered registration token

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I use `cordova-plugin-fcm`, and call its two functions `onTokenRefresh`, and `getToken` to get the FCM token of my device (Android). They both give me the same FCM token value, which used to work and my app used to receive notifications.

However now, I cannot send any notifications to the device anymore even from Firebase console which gives me this error:

```
Unregistered registration token
```

I haven't uninstalled the app or changed it. Why does it say this token is unregistered although `getToken` and `onTokenRefresh` seem to work and give me the same fcm token that I had from the beginning?